Texture2D type not as expected with raylib Rust
I have the following code block in which I am trying to create a new Texture2D:
let texture: Texture2D = *handle
        .load_texture(&thread, &path)
        .expect(&format!("Failed to load texture: {}", path));

According to the documentation, the load_texture() function should return a Texture2D
raylib::core::texture::RaylibHandle
pub fn load_texture(&mut self, _: &RaylibThread, filename: &str) -> Result<Texture2D, String>

However when trying to do this, I'm met with a mismatched type, Texture instead of the expected Texture2D
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/engine/texture.rs:13:30
   |
13 |       let texture: Texture2D = *handle
   |  __________________---------___^
   | |                  |
   | |                  expected due to this
14 | |         .load_texture(&thread, &path)
15 | |         .expect(&format!("Failed to load texture: {}", path));
   | |_____________________________________________________________^ expected `Texture2D`, found `Texture`


load_texture does return a Texture2D, but you're immediately de-referencing that into a raylib::ffi::Texture.
I suspect you were intending to just de-reference handle - however, the * operator applies to the entire following expression, not just the rest of the line!
To specifically de-reference handle, you would need to do (*handle) instead - though that would likely just cause a different error, since you would be trying to move out of an immutable reference.
I think the real solution is just to remove the * entirely!

Got it eventually, though this definitely pointed me in the right direction. I had to mess with the way I was passing my handle to the function :p
